# Monitor turn on or wake up command in windows 7 SP1 x64

Tags: vb.net

I have the code below, that does successfully "wake up" a sleeping monitor, but it only momentarily wakes it up, it flashes on and then back off. I've tried various timers and loops to reissue the command, but its hard on the cpu by the look of it, does anyone have any ideas on how to get it to turn on the screen for say 10 minutes, or even just turn it on and wait for the OS to turn it off again later?

Ive also looked into the whole send keys thing, but that didnt seem to do anything in windows 7, An important note to make, the dredit for this code in the most part is thanks to the members of StackOverflow! Cheers

Here is the code:

```
Public Class MonitorHelper

Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
Private SC_MONITORPOWER As New IntPtr(&HF170)
Private HWND_BROADCAST As Integer = (&HFFFF&)
Private MONITOR_ON As New IntPtr(-1)
Private MONITOR_OFF As New IntPtr(2)


Public Sub TurnOnScreen(ByVal form As Form)
    NativeMethods.PostMessage(New HandleRef(Me, HWND_BROADCAST), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_ON)
End Sub

<SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()> _
Private Class NativeMethods

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Public Shared Function PostMessage( _
            ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, _
            ByVal message As Integer, _
            ByVal lParam As IntPtr, _
            ByVal wParam As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

End Class
End Class

public class form3
Private monitorHelper1 As New MonitorHelper
End Class
```

Calling the monitor to turn on:

```
monitorHelper1.TurnOnScreen(Me)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO looking at this from the other direction, not how to turn it on and how to make it not go to sleep in a round about way, I have this working code... Thanks to Hannes Du Preez.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 'APIs
Imports Microsoft.Win32         'For System Events

Public Class frmMonitor

<FlagsAttribute()> _
Public Enum EXECUTION_STATE As UInteger ' Determine Monitor State
    ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = &H40
    ES_CONTINUOUS = &H80000000UI
    ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = &H2
    ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = &H1
    ' Legacy flag, should not be used.
    ' ES_USER_PRESENT = 0x00000004
End Enum

'Enables an application to inform the system that it is in use, thereby preventing the system from entering sleep or turning off the display while the application is running.

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function SetThreadExecutionState(ByVal esFlags As EXECUTION_STATE) As    EXECUTION_STATE
End Function

'This function queries or sets system-wide parameters, and updates the user profile during the process.
<DllImport("user32", EntryPoint:="SystemParametersInfo", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function SystemParametersInfo(ByVal uAction As Integer, ByVal uParam As Integer, ByVal lpvParam As String, ByVal fuWinIni As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Private Const SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT As Int32 = 15

Public Sub KeepMonitorActive()

    SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED + EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS) 'Do not Go To Sleep

End Sub

Public Sub RestoreMonitorSettings()

    SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS) 'Restore Previous Settings, ie, Go To Sleep Again

End Sub
```