# Turn on display/stop screen saver

Tags: c#, winforms, smartcard, smartcard-reader

My applications input is from a smart card reader, I'm using this smart card reader https://www.hidglobal.com/products/readers/omnikey/5021

The PC i'll be using will either use the screen saver or have the display turned off after being idle for a while.

I'm trying to find a way to turn on the display of a computer or stop the screen saver. My application is still responding to the card reader even if the display is turned off or the screen saver is running except the display won't turn on or the screen saver won't stop like when you press a key on the keyboard or move the mouse.

Is there just a setting i'm missing? is there any code that I can run after reading a card to turn on the monitor display or stop the screen saver?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664395/monitor-turn-on-or-wake-up-command-in-windows-7-sp1-x64/27686362#27686362

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PostMessage API to "wake up" the screen saver.  Here is a link that describes it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/140723

Here is an example of how to implement this in C#

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17067/Controlling-The-Screen-Saver-With-C

Comment: How exactly do I declare this so I can use it?

Comment: Sorry, I added a link to a C# example